# How to know where verbose is printed in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I use Keras training a simple model.

```
# Design model
model = Sequential()
[...] # Architecture
model.compile()
```

In addition, I use the **fit_generator** function to output the result where the parameter **verbose = 1**

```
# Train model on dataset
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    verbose=1)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Epoch 1/2
104/104 [==============================] - 72s 456us/step - loss: 0.2823 - acc: 
0.8511 - val_loss: 0.2933 - val_acc: 0.8629
```

I want to know where verbose **is printed**, but I can't find it...

```
104/104 [==============================]
```

I want to see how verbose calculates 104/104

Answer (score 0):

Setting verbose sets up a [`ProgbarLogger` over here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L89-L95), with the mode set to `steps`.

In that mode, the value is incremented [at the end of every batch](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L588-L592).